# «im Andenken» vs. «in Andenken»

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Heisst es «in Andenken» oder «im Andenken» an jemanden? Im Duden findet sich als Beispiel unter dem Begriff «Andenken»:

> bei jemandem in gutem Andenken stehen

Andererseits lese ich in den Widmungen zahlreicher Bücher «*im* Andenken».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hier ist nur der Dativ üblich, also *im Andenken*. Beachte, dass das Beispiel aus dem Duden ebenfalls im Dativ steht, der Dativ wird allerdings in der Dativendung von *gutem* markiert, daher steht hier *in*; **im gutem* wäre falsch. Dennoch ist *in gutem* ebenso Dativ wie das alleinstehende *im*.